# Why is MSBuild.exe skipping important files

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-mvc-5

### Short introduction

My goal is to get IIS 8 to run an asp.net 4.5 website. Currently I have a CI server that pulls from version control and builds the web application with MSBuild.exe with this line of code

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe C:\project\WebApplication\WebApplication.csproj /T:Package
```

### The problem

The problem I am facing is that I dont understand why things like Controllers, Viewmodels, Models etc. that are pure C# code are being ignored or skipped when the project is being built with MSBuild.exe and packaged.

The package that MSBuild.exe returns only contains

- Areas
- bin
- Content
- fonts
- Scripts
- Views

and is missing many folders including

- Controllers
- Models
- etc.

### Questions

1. Is this normal?
2. Why does this happen?
3. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Seems to be
2. No idea, but the functionality of the cs files is now probably part of dll's in the bin folder.
3. I was not doing anything wrong. I just thought this was a problem. I managed to get the asp.net web application to work on the web server like it does on the developer machine.